# iTerm2 disable full screen keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, iterm

Any way to disable fn(Globe)-F keyboard shortcut for full screen? Doesn't show up in Preferences->Keys.

[image]

Comment: There’s no Fn-F shortcut.  Do you mean the “[clover](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/universal-set-2/30/universal-set-2045-512.png)” symbol(⌘)?

Comment: There is for me. iTerm2 3.4.15 on M1 Monterey

Comment: I use a 3rd party mechanical keyboard, so I forgot that the new M1s have a globe key.  The systemwide command is Ctrl-Cmd-F which makes it curious as to why iTerm woukd remap this.  This key combo is coded into the app

Answer (score 2):

With https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/commit/d44f8f16287c420eea54528255e8385e114f4c4f you can use iTerm2 -> Settings -> Keys -> + -> CMD+Enter set to Ignore

Answer (score 0):

Open **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**:

- Application: select "iTerm.app"
- Menu Title: type "Toggle Full Screen" from the "View" menu
- Keyboard Shortcut: press another shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>